# How to get items returned from an array in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which returns an array of two variables.

```
function exampleFunction() {
    var variable1 = 'test';
    var variable2 = 'test2';

    return [variable1, variable2];
}
```

Now in another function when I call `exampleFunction` how do I get the items from the array that is returned from it.

I have tried using:

```
if (exampleFunction[0] == true) {
    // do code here
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To retrieve the values, you need to execute the function.

Update from

```
exampleFunction[0]
```

to

```
exampleFunction()[0] // paints "test"
```

Comment: Ah thanks, just a little rookie mistake on my part! No wonder it kept returning undefined!

Comment: @bladeedg - Sometimes it happens :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the returned array into an other variable, and then access from it :

```
var myArray = exampleFunction()
myArray[0]
```

Hope it answers your question !

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me see my ways!